# Aboriginal fonts cause wrong page size warnings

Tags: beamer, xetex, fontspec

On texlive on Ubuntu I've installed texlive-xetex and texlive-humanities.  I find that on a simple document with only a \maketitle, using \setmainfont{Aboriginal Serif} creates many warnings.

```
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Aboriginal Serif} 
\title{Simple test title}
\author{Jawguy Chooser} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Upon compilation:

```
jawguy@salix:~/$ xelatex test.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.

[snip lots of messages from Babel, beamer, hyperref, fontspec, etc]

No file test.nav.
[1] (./test.aux)
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [234.549 -0.0126757 241.603 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [240.527 -0.0126757 249.573 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified. 
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [248.497 -0.0126757 255.551 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [255.547 -0.0126757 261.604 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [260.528 -0.0126757 266.586 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [265.51 -0.0126757 271.567 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [270.491 -0.0126757 276.548 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [276.544 -0.0126757 282.602 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [281.526 -0.0126757 287.583 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [286.507 -0.0126757 292.564 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [291.488 -0.0126757 297.546 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [297.542 -0.0126757 303.599 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [302.523 -0.0126757 308.58 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [307.504 -0.0126757 313.562 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [312.486 -0.0126757 318.543 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [318.539 -0.0126757 328.582 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [327.506 -0.0126757 339.541 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [339.537 -0.0126757 347.587 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [346.51 -0.0126757 353.564 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
** WARNING ** Annotation out of page boundary.
** WARNING ** Current page's MediaBox: [0 0 362.835 272.126]
** WARNING ** Annotation: [352.488 -0.0126757 360.538 13.0283]
** WARNING ** Maybe incorrect paper size specified.
 )
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Any insight?  Overall the output looks fine, but I can see that there are negative numbers in the "annotations" I guess that's a negative y value.  There are so many of these warnings that it makes it difficult to find actual problems when I start making a more complicated document.  The terminal gets flooded with many hundreds of these per page.

---

EDIT:

I'm leaving the question open, because I'd love to get some further information about this problem, but I have found a workaround which makes the proliferation of warnings go away.  I can add [Scale=0.9] to the \setmainfont options and voilà! No more warnings.  Nevertheless, I'd love to both know how a fontsize ended up setting things into negative placements and I'd love to find a more principled way than trial and error for correcting such weirdness (how can I choose a value for Scale which corrects whatever error without overcorrecting?).

Comment: Even `Scale=0.999` should give no warning. Weird.

Comment: Beamer loads hyperref and creates a lot of links, eg for the navigation. An unusual sized font could create an link area that is outside the page size, but without the font it is not easy to rest. Is the font available somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what "it's not easy to rest." means.  If you're looking for the Aboriginal Serif font you can find them on languagegeek.com or on debian/ubuntu/etc you can say 'apt-get install fonts-lg-aboriginal'.